# Async FTP Library

Tags: c++, c, ftp

Is there any cross platform and asynchronous FTP client library for C or C++?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have trouble finding one that is both cross-platform and async

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html)? It's well-known, widely-used, and supports async FTP. I would imagine it's cross-platform as well.

As a bonus, it's a much smaller library to link against than, e.g., all of Qt.

Comment: Yes that seems like a better bet.  It *is* portable.

Comment: Looks nice. Is there any example of Async FTP with libcurl?

Comment: Check out the docs on "Multiple transfers using the multi interface" - http://curl.linux-mirror.org/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

What about [Qftp](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.2/qftp.html)?

This is part of Qt, so code should be portable.  Might be only for GUI apps though...

> The QFtp class provides an
>   implementation of the client side of
>   FTP protocol.
>
> The class works asynchronously, so
>   there are no blocking functions. If an
>   operation cannot be executed
>   immediately, the function will still
>   return straight away and the operation
>   will be scheduled for later execution.
>   The results of scheduled operations
>   are reported via signals. This
>   approach depends on the event loop
>   being in operation.

Comment: Definitely not *only* for GUI apps, but (caveat): it is a large library to link against.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I know one, but why don't you take a look at, for example, FileZilla's source code (http://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/trunk/src/engine/ )? It's open source, take advantage of it. Probably you won't use this code as-is, but at least it'll give some ideas to get you going.

Comment: This seems excessive when nicely packaged libraries already exist.